# How to concatinate 3 ints into unsigned long long?

Tags: c++, formatting, c++11

Say, we get `int A` `333`; `int B` `4444` and `int C` `5454` we want to concatenate them into one `unsigned long long` `000333 004444 005454 00` (with format like 0/1 int sign, int). How to do such formating in C++, and are there any C++11 tools that can simplify process?

Comment: Good question, but may I ask why?

Comment: 3 32-bit `int`s don't generally fit in a 64-bit `unsigned long long`...

Answer (score 2):

You could make strings from the ints using [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), concatenate as necessary, then convert to long long using [std::stoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 2):

Do you just mean this?

```
unsigned int A = 333;
unsigned int B = 4444;
unsigned int C = 5454;

unsigned long long r = A*100000000000000ULL + B*100000000ULL + C*100ULL;
```

Proof it works: http://ideone.com/XWFdU

Comment: There *can't* be a proof that it works, because it *can't* work. 3 32bit values have 96bits of information. You can't fit 96bits of information into 64bits

Comment: It works for the example the op chose. And the example of the op looks like his numbers won't get bigger than 6 digits, in which case the result would fit into `unsigned long long`.

Comment: the `static_cast`s here are unnecessary and only make the code noisy.

Comment: True, they were leftovers from when I was writing the code. Also you can make the code more readable by using exponents, which I didn't.