# Converting an Integer Array into a Number

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

Think I have an integer array like this:

```
a[0]=60; a[1]=321; a[2]=5;
```

now I want to convert the whole of this array into an integer number, for example `int b` become 603215 after running the code.

How to do it?

Comment: I do have to say I've never thought about doing this, or seen anyone else trying to do it. Kudos for the originality, or picking a question that's hidden itself from me.

Comment: This is similar, but simpler than [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187898/how-to-concatinate-3-ints-into-unsigned-long-long/). My solution applies to this problem, but since you don't care about formatting then the `stringstream` solution seems simpler.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a `std::stringstream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    int arr[] = {60, 321, 5};

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof arr / sizeof arr [0]; ++i)
        ss << arr [i];

    int result;
    ss >> result;
    std::cout << result; //603215
}
```

Note that in C++11 that mildly ugly loop can be replaced with this:

```
for (int i : arr)
    ss << i;
```

Also, seeing as how there is a good possibility of overflow, the string form of the number can be accessed with `ss.str()`. To get around overflow, it might be easier working with that than trying to cram it into an integer. Negative values should be taken into consideration, too, as this will only work (and make sense) if the first value is negative.

Answer (score 7):

```
int a[] = {60, 321, 5};

int finalNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    int num = a[i];
    if (num != 0) {
        while (num > 0) {
            finalNumber *= 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        finalNumber += a[i];
    } else {
        finalNumber *= 10;
    }
}
```

finalNumber has a result: **603215**

Comment: Just a couple of other things, the first being a Java->C++ one: 1. Arrays aren't classes in C++, and don't have a `length` member. It's typically better to use `std::vector` instead, as it offers the functionality. 2. `a` should be `arr`.

Comment: @Kalai Thank you too, Nice and Smart Answer :))

Comment: @Kalai your code has a problem, think a[0]=50; a[1]=1; a[2]=0; then the result should be 5010, but your code will skip 0 and will show 501.

Comment: @Stranger Thanks for your comment. You are having good analysing power. I have edited the code. Now, it will work.

Comment: @Kalai it is not working yet!!! use int a[] = {60, 321, 0}; as the first line and you will get no answer at all !!!

Comment: @Kalai I was wrong :( Your code is amazing and it is working fine, I was doing something wrong in my code. so thanks :))

Answer (score 6):

Concat all the numbers as a string and then convert that to number

```
#include <string>
int b = std::stoi("603215");
```

Comment: I know the question isn't too specific, but I would imagine the array elements can be arbitrary (to the point where it doesn't overflow the integer). Hardcoding a string value won't get around that. The function is a good alternative start (assuming you have C++11) to the stringstream, though.

Answer (score 3):

This algorithm will work:

1. Convert all the integer values of array into string using for loop.
2. Append all the string values now to one string from index 0 to length of array.
3. Change that string into an integer again.

Comment: I made your algorithm easier to follow when reading it. FFR, there's a numbered list button at the top of the editing space.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate  the array and convert the values into string. Then concatenate all of them and convert back to integer.

```
#include <string>

int a[] = {60, 321, 5};
std::string num = "";
for(auto val : a)
    num += a;
int b = std::stoi(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

###### Array to Integer conversion

Number should be stored in opposite way

```
 for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        ans += num[i]*pow(10,i);
    }
```