# string conversion c++

Tags: c++, char

I have a string and the first element is for example 'a'. I already declared a variable called a ( so int a=1 for example). My question now is, how can I convert the whole string to numbers (a=1,b=2,c=3,...z=26)? Example:

`string str="hello";` this has to be changed to `"85121215"` and then changed to 85121215.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please post some code and explain what have you tried so far.

Comment: Where do you want the numbers (output, container, replacing the letter)?

Comment: example: string str="hello"; this has to be changed to "85121215" and then changed to 85121215

Comment: What will you do with "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"? An integer representation by your definition doesn't fit in any built-in type.

Comment: @jrok, You need a "the" in there. Anyway, I'd probably go with your solution, followed by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201015/converting-an-integer-array-into-a-number), assuming it's a requirement of the program specifications that the input does fit.

Comment: it's actually not meant for such big words or sentences.

Comment: @chris nitpicker, you've made me google it :) thx

Answer (score 3):

```
// transformation itself doesn't care what encoding we use
std::string transform_string(std::string const &in, std::function<int(char)> op)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(),
                   std::ostream_iterator<int>(out),
                   op);
    return out.str();
}

// the per-character mapping is easy to isolate
int ascii_az_map(char ch)
{
    if (ch < 'a' || ch > 'z') {
        std::ostringstream error;
        error << "character '" << ch << "'=" << (int)ch
              << " not in range a-z";
        throw std::out_of_range(error.str());
    }
    return 1 + ch - 'a';
}

// so we can support other encodings if necessary
// NB. ebdic_to_ascii isn't actually implemented here
int ebcdic_az_map(char ch)
{
    return ascii_az_map(ebcdic_to_ascii(ch));
}

// and even detect the platform encoding automatically (w/ thanks to Phresnel)
// (you can still explicitly select a non-native encoding if you want)
int default_az_map(char ch)
{
    #if ('b'-'a' == 1) && ('j' - 'i' == 1)
        return ascii_az_map(ch);
    #elif ('j'-'i' == 8)
        return ebcdic_az_map(ch);
    #else
        #error "unknown character encoding"
    #endif
}

// use as:
std::string str = "hello";
std::string trans = transform_string(str, ascii_az_map);
// OR ... transform_string(str, ebcdic_az_map);
```

---

Note that since the per-character mapping is completely isolated, it's really easy to change the mapping to a lookup table, support different encodings etc.

Comment: or isolate at compile time: `#if 'B'-'A' == 1 && 'C'-'A' == 2` or `enum letters_are_conti { val = 'B'-'A' == 1 && ... }`. I once did this.

Comment: absolutely - write `default_az_map` with preprocessor magic in the body, and just use that

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is a bit small:

```
"hello" = "85121215
h = 8
e = 5
l = 12
o = 15
```

I assume you mean that

```
a = 1
b = 2
...
z = 26
```

in which case it is not that hard:

```
std::string meh_conv(char c) {
    switch(c) { // (or `switch(tolower(c))` and save some typing)
    case 'a': case 'A': return "1";
    case 'b': case 'B': return "2";
    ....
    case 'z': case 'Z': return "26";
    ....
    // insert other special characters here
    }
    throw std::range_error("meh");
}

std::string meh_conv(std::string const &src) {
    std::string dest;
    for (const auto c : s)
       dest += meh_conv(c);
    return dest;
}
```

<strike>or use `std::transform()`:</strike>

```
#include <algorithm>

std::string dest;
std::transform (src.begin(), src.end(), back_inserter(dest),
                meh_conv)
```

(doesn't work for different incoming and outgoing types, at least not as is)

---

Addendum.

You possibly want to parametrize the replacement map:

```
std::map<char, std::string> repl;
repl['a'] = repl['A'] = "0";
repl[' '] = " ";


std::string src = "hello";
std::string dest;
for (const auto c : src) dest += repl[c];
```

Comment: Might as well `switch (tolower(c))` and save yourself some typing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a simple example. It creates a map what contains the a-1, b-2, c-3 ... pairs. Then concatenate the values using a stringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "abc";
    std::map<char,int> dictionary;
    int n = 1;
    for(char c='a'; c<='z'; c++)
        dictionary.insert(std::pair<char,int>(c,n++));

    //EDIT if you want uppercase characters too:
    n=1;
    for(char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++)
        dictionary.insert(std::pair<char,int>(c,n++));        

    std::stringstream strstream;

    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++)
        strstream<<dictionary[str[i]];

    std::string numbers = strstream.str();

    std::cout<<numbers;

    return 0;
}
```

C++ experts probably going to kill me for this solution, but it works ;)

Comment: It's got the same problem as @infact's solution, it assumes characters `a` to `z` are contiguos.

Comment: @RedX standard only guarantees chars 0-9 to be contiguos. In practise though, yes, a-z are contiguos.

Comment: For a difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC. I'd think a note would be fine, though. There's no good way to keep it portable. The only option I see is going through each letter individually for a map/function.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem then. Could you write an example where this doesn't work?

Comment: @bali182, Anything j and up won't if EBCDIC is being used.

Comment: @chris: What's the 'j' in 'Anything j', sounds relevant?

Comment: @phresnel, As shown in the link, in EBCDIC, 'a' through 'i' are all contiguous, but `'j' != 'i' + 1`.

Comment: @chris: Ah, you referred to a simple letter. I thought 'j' might be something IBM or so :D

Answer (score 0):

Easy Approach, 
you can find mod of char with 96 (ASCII value before a), as result it will always give you values in range 1-26.

```
int value;
string s;
cin>>s;
for(int i=0; i<s.size();i++){
    value = s[j]%96;
    cout<<value<<endl;

}
```